# Gramps syncing with Dropbox or via second Genealogy program?

Tags: gramps

I use [Gramps](https://gramps-project.org/) almost daily and I am very satisfied with it. The only downside it has, in my opinion, is the fact that synchronising its database is fairly risky via Dropbox, s. [here](http://gramps.1791082.n4.nabble.com/Gramps-inside-Dropbox-td4594898.html), or [hassle-ish](http://gramps.1791082.n4.nabble.com/Sync-Gramps-between-two-machines-td2291961.html) via USB stick.

Does someone use another program for the sole purpose of synchronising the xml (or gpkg) file exported from Gramps (v. 4.2.2.) on PC 1 (Linux) in order to import it to Gramps (v. 4.2.2.) on PC 2 (Win Vista)? If so, which one?

Does someone has day-to-day experience with Gramps and Dropbox-Sync on two computer? Is it really that dangerous?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be dangerous. For example, on Linux, you might get an automatic update of the low-level BSDDB database library. This can make it so that you can no longer open the file on the other OS (or even under Linux for that matter). Good news: Gramps 5.0 (later this year) will allow you to use a real database server, or a better DB file (sqlite) so these worries should go away.

Comment: Sounds great, Doug! But how will the new database server function in Gramps 5.0? How can one sync the sqlite database? Looking forward to it already!

Comment: You won't need to sync it... they can both use the same file at the same time (I think that will work). Or you can use a real db server with both Windows and Linux connecting onto it.

Comment: Awesome! Great job by the way for Gramps to you and the other developer!